# Cypher: How to use special character relationships within foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With the time tree, if we're to use relationships of the kind

```
(Root)-[:`2016`]-(Year)-[:`1`]-(Month)-[:`7`]-(Day)
```

from a jdbc client; is there a way to do that with PreparedStatements ?

If not how to handle the

```
foreach
```

section to handle multiple years / months / days with normal Statements ?

Thanks in anticipation ..

Comment: I'm not really sure what your trying to achieve... The 2016 value would be better modeled as a field on a node with a 'Year' label. And the same with Month and Day

Answer (score 0):

No, because relationship types cannot be [parameterized](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) in a Cypher statement.

You'll have to build the query yourself as a String and then supply that to the PreparedStatement (with hardcoded relationship types). This isn't good because your query will not be cached. The same will apply when you query the timetree. A better approach would be the one suggested by Joe in the comments.

A [timetree module](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html) is available from GraphAware if you'd rather not manage the tree yourself.

Disclaimer: I work at GraphAware.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it resolved your question, thanks

Comment: Thanks @Joe, @Luanne.

Just curious, if the loss from not being prepared / cached, has a chance to be offset by the fact that, with hard coded [:`2015`] kind relationships, traversal / pattern matching should be much faster than relying on a filter like year.year = 2015

Comment: The surest way to know is to measure it against a representative dataset